# htaccess: Redirect file.php to file.html, and block direct access to the file.php at the same time

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to **redirect a url help.html to help.php (internally)** using .htaccess rewrite, but at the same time, I would like to **give a 404 error message if someone tries to access help.php directly**.

I've seen alot of tutorials, and alot of questions answered, but none to this specific problem.

Is this possible?

**Edit:**
For someone looking at the url from the outside, he would only see that help.html exists, but not help.php (even though internally only help.php exists, but not help.html) :)

Comment: How do you intend making the distinction between redirecting a request for help.php or giving a 404 error for it?

Comment: Based on your question, there's no way to distinguish between when you want to do those two things.  Just pick the one that makes the most sense (probably a redirect).

Comment: there's no reason to give 404. just redirect using 301 in the htaccess file (like @hughes suggested)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Files help.php>
   order allow,deny
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule help.html$ help.php [L]
```

And you might wanna add

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` to make the PHP execute now show as HTML/TEXT.

Edit:
And you can give 404 error (cuz this htaccess will give 403 error) by adding this `ErrorDocument 403 404.php` and put 404 error HTML code in that page

Comment: this is very, very close, but it still gives me a 403 (404 with the error document redirect) when I try to access help.html...

Comment: it's like after i've denied access to the help.php, the RewriteRule, seems to jump into that denial automaticly, eventhough I'am rewriting(directing) it.

Answer (score 0):

in your .htaccess file, you can use "permanent redirect" command:

```
Redirect 301 /help.php /help.html
```

Answer (score -2):

use a meta tag redirect to the help.html page from the help.php (404 page) after x seconds

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="10; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/help.html">
```